# How to un-share shared printer?

Tags: c#, windows, printing, share, shared

I'm developing 'Share Monitoring Application' via C# and it's monitoring the sharing activities and I'm using these APIs to implement enumerate shared items/un-sharing shared items.


**Api used:**

```
NetShareEnum
NetShareDel
```

`NetShareEnum` to enumerate all shared items and `NetShareDel` to delete shared items (=unshare).
I used `SHChangeNotify` to remove shared mark and directories working fine. 
(Delete shared item using `NetShareDel` is not affected immediately.)

But printer state is not affected by `SHChangeNotify`. Which mean after deleting shared printer via `NetShareDel` and call `SHChangeNotify` with `SHCNE_NETUNSHARE` and `SHCNF_PATHW`. Also I used `SHCNE_NETUNSHARE` and `SHCNF_PRINTERW` too, but nothing happened.

**Shared printer's state mark:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZGrI.png
In this picture, you can see the users the right side of check circle and that indicate printer is shared.
But after calling `NetShareDel` to unshared shared printer and it's succeed, but shared mark is disappear.

Anyone know how to implement this? I'm waiting for your help. :D
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried WMI and it works on my computer, but other computers throw an exception. And I think the reason of application throw an exception is the one of required library is missing on the computer.
So I'm looking for the API that can be used instead of the WMI.

Finally I found the `GetPrinter` and `SetPrinter` from the MSDN.

And also I found `PRINTER_INFO_5` structure. According to MSDN, `Attributes` field indicate the printer's attribute including printer is shared or not. And this can be checked `Attributes` field has `PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_SHARED` value.

Anyway, this problem can be solved only `OpenPrinter`, `GetPrinter` and `SetPrinter`.

This image shows the before and after calling 'UnsharePrinter' method.
[image: Before and After the calling UnsharePrinter method]

This is the method I made to un-share the shared printer.
(Un-sharing the shared printer can be performed via `NetShareDel`, but it cannot notify **printer is un-shared** to the system.)

```
Boolean UnsharePrinter(String printerName) {
    // fill PRINTER_DEFAULTS structure
    // and set DesiredAccess to PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER to 
    // get rights to call SetPrinter
    PRINTER_DEFAULTS pd;
    pd.pDatatype = IntPtr.Zero;
    pd.pDevMode = IntPtr.Zero;
    pd.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER;

    IntPtr pDefaults = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PRINTER_DEFAULTS)));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(pd, pDefaults, true);

    IntPtr hPrinter;
    // open the printer
    if ( !OpenPrinter(printerName, out hPrinter, pDefaults) ) {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pDefaults);
        return false;
    }

    // first, call Zero pointer and 0 size to get minimum required space
    IntPtr pInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
    Int32 pcbNeeded;
    GetPrinter(hPrinter, 5, pInfo, 0, out pcbNeeded);

    // alloc reqiured space and call GetPrinter
    pInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(pcbNeeded);
    if ( !GetPrinter(hPrinter, 5, pInfo, pcbNeeded, out pcbNeeded) ) {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pInfo);
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        return false;
    }

    // pointer to structure
    PRINTER_INFO_5 pi5 = (PRINTER_INFO_5) Marshal.PtrToStructure(pInfo, typeof(PRINTER_INFO_5));
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pInfo);

    // if printer is not shared, release the memory and exit
    if ( (pi5.Attributes & PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_SHARED) == 0 ) {
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        return false;
    }

    // remove the shared flag
    pi5.Attributes &= ~PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_SHARED;

    // alloc pointer and make structure as pointer
    pInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PRINTER_INFO_5)));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(pi5, pInfo, true);

    // set printer
    Boolean r = SetPrinter(hPrinter, 5, pInfo, 0);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pInfo);
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);

    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going via WMI?
I haven't used it myself to "unshare" a printer, but I use it alot in an application to edit printers and printer-ports in other ways.
I would think something like this should do the trick.

The Win32_Printer class looks like it has a "shared" property, so I would suggest trying to switch it to false.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I haven't tested this code with unsharing, but it is the exact same code I use to change other properties.

```
//get the printer(s) through wmi query
//prep query
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(string.Format("select * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name = '{0}'", "printername"));
//create scope (connect to server)
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\serverName\\root\\cimv2");
//search for printers
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
//get collection of printers (should be 0 or 1, but it returns a collection regardless because of the query
ManagementObjectCollection printers = search.Get();
//iterate through the 0-1 printers and set Shared to false
foreach (ManagementObject printer in printers)
{
    printer.SetPropertyValue("Shared",false);
    printer.put();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering!! solved the problem with this way. Thanks a lot!!